# Trying to provide hyperlink in HTML based on ng-if condition...not working

Tags: angular-ng-if

I want to provide a link on a text based condtion utilizing `ng-if`. 
If functions return true I want to provide the link, otherwise display just the value with no link.

```
<th style="text-align:left">
<span ng-if="(mandalLink())">
<a ng-href="/#!/l2-mandal/{{department}}/{{d}}" title="Click to see data at Mandal Level">{{d}}</a>
</span>
<span ng-if="(!mandalLink())"> {{d}} </span>
</th>
```

I have used `ng-if` at other places and its working but in this case it's not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you need any additional info/help not covered in my answer?

Comment: FYI: The brackets are not needed around the function, just `<span ng-if="mandalLink()">` is fine.. BTW: Can you provide the code of your `mandalLink()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .html-file try:

```
<th style="text-align:left">
  <span ng-if="showLink">
    <a ng-href="/#!/l2-mandal/{{department}}/{{d}}" title="Click to see data at Mandal Level">{{d}}</a>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="!showLink"> {{d}} </span>
</th>
```

In your .ts-file (on ngOnInit or where you get/assign a value to 'department'..)

```
showLink;

getDepartmentOrWhatEver(){
    ... // your logic getting 'department' assigned
   if (department == "") {
      this.showLink= false;
   }
   else {
      this.showLink= true;
   }
}
```

From the docs on ng-if:

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.
>
> ngIf differs from ngShow and ngHide in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property. A common case when this difference is significant is when using css selectors that rely on an element's position within the DOM, such as the :first-child or :last-child pseudo-classes.

FYI: The brackets are not needed around the function, just `<span ng-if="mandalLink()">` is fine..